# Porque o servidor envia 2 chaves públicas no handshake do TLS?

Tags: https, tls

Durante a troca de informações no handshake do TLS, o servidor envia uma chave pública junto com o certificado. O    servidor   envia também
uma segunda chave   pública (Server  Key Exchange) caso o   cliente aceite   o  certificado.

Se o servidor já enviou uma chave pública junto com o certificado, qual a necessidade de uma segunda chave pública?

Comment: Acredito que a chave pública é para realizar o DH, ou sobre ECDH ou usando X25519. Uma outra opção é poque o certificado contem outros certificados, como o intermediário, e o cliente pode apenas ter conhecimento da autoridade, não dos intermediários ou sub-CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @Inkeliz já falou, a questão é que o certificado enviado pelo servidor, na verdade, não é um certificado, mas uma corrente de certificados.
O certificado propriamente dito não é assinado diretamente pela agência certificadora, mas por uma agência intermediária. Entretanto, o browser só conhece as agências certificadoras, sendo assim, é necessário criar um *corrente* de chaves públicas até atingir a assinatura da certificadora raíz.

Caso precise de mais detalhes, existe [esse artigo da IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q009940_.htm), que explica de forma mais detalhada o processo de segurança do TSL.